# Add "active" class to TD if "active" class is in thead

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

I don't do much jQuery so this is probably easy for someone else.  I have a series of tables.  Some need to have a specific column to be active.  My problem now obviously is that with the code below all tables highlight the specific `$indexNum` value and add the class active.

I need to say.
"Did you find the active class on one of the `th` tags in the `thead`?"

Yes, than find all the tds inside this specific table and apply the active class to the same column as you found in the the thead.

No, then don't do anything to this table.

**This is what I have so far:**

```
var $indexNum = $('thead tr th.active').index();
$('td:nth-child('+($indexNum+1)+')').addClass('active');
```

Comment: So you need to find the table and select the rows in that table.... So loop over the tables and find the active column in that table

Answer (score 1):

I think something like this would do the job:

```
$('table th.active').each(function () {
  var index = $(this).index()
  $(this).parents('table').find('td:nth-child(' + (index + 1) + ')').addClass('active')
})
```

Comment: YUP THAT WORKED LIKE A CHARM. THX